# Cannot configure log42j using Fuseki

Tags: fuseki

This question was answered and is related to the version of Fuseki. It is now resolved.

I am working with a Fuseki triplestore and want to set up logging. I follow the instructions here - https://apache.googlesource.com/jena/+/jena-fuseki-new-ui/docs/fuseki-logging.md

I download the default log42j.properties file and put it into the "current" directory, and run Fuseki. I do not get any indication that log42j has been read in. Am I following the instructions correctly?

Kind regards,

Fuseki on starup up -

[2021-03-08 15:35:10] Server     INFO  Apache Jena Fuseki 3.13.1
[2021-03-08 15:35:11] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_HOME=C:\Users\user\Desktop\triplestore\fusekiDB.
[2021-03-08 15:35:11] Config     INFO  FUSEKI_BASE=C:\Users\user\Desktop\triplestore\fusekiDB\run
[2021-03-08 15:35:11] Config     INFO  Shiro file: file://C:\Users\user\Desktop\triplestore\fusekiDB\run\shiro.ini
[2021-03-08 15:35:11] Config     INFO  Configuration file: C:\Users\user\Desktop\triplestore\fusekiDB\run\config.ttl
[2021-03-08 15:35:11] Config     INFO  Load configuration: file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/triplestore/fusekiDB/run/configuration/db_test.ttl
[2021-03-08 15:35:11] Config     INFO  Register: /db_test
[2021-03-08 15:35:11] Server     INFO  Started 2021/03/08 15:35:11 GMT on port 3030

Contents of log4j2.properties -

[image]

My folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The documentation states the following:

> The preferred customization is to use a custom log4j2.properties file
> in the directory where Fuseki Main is run.
>
> For the war file packaging, the log4j2.properties should go in
> FUSEKI_BASE which defaults to /etc/fuseki on Linux.
>
> For the standalone webapp server, FUSEKI_BASE defaults to directory
> run/ within the directory where the server is run.

========================== Final Edit ===================

Please note the following:

If you are running a WAR file, then the log4j.properties needs to exists in your unpacked war.  If you are running from command line, then it needs to exists in the same directory as your server.jar

> When running from a WAR file in a webapp container such as Apache
> Tomcat, the logging configuration comes from the file
> log4j2.properties in the root of the unpacked war file, e.g.
> /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/fuseki/log4j2.properties.
>
> The name of the file is taken from web.xml:
>
> log4jConfiguration log4j2.properties
>
> This only applies when running in a webapp container. When run from
> the command line, the server looks for log4j2.properties in the
> current directory and if not found, uses a built-in configuration.
>
> This logging goes to the standard output.

Tested by updating the log4j.properties file which exists in the same folder as the fuseki-server.jar and as you can see the logging time changes from printing only seconds to milliseconds.

The update I applied was:

```
ORIGINAL: appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{HH:mm:ss} %-5p %-15c{1} :: %m%n 
CHANGED TO: appender.console.layout.pattern = %d{HH:mm:ss:sss} %-5p %-15c{1} :: m%n
```

[image]

---

```
ezsusmu@SE-00018098 /cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/ezsusmu/Downloads/apache-jena-fuseki-3.17.0
$ java -jar fuseki-server.jar --memTDB /Susan
16:13:30 INFO  Server          :: Apache Jena Fuseki 3.17.0
16:13:31 INFO  Config          :: FUSEKI_HOME=C:\Documents and Settings\ezsusmu\Downloads\apache-jena-fuseki-3.17.0\.
16:13:31 INFO  Config          :: FUSEKI_BASE=C:\Documents and Settings\ezsusmu\Downloads\apache-jena-fuseki-3.17.0\run
16:13:31 INFO  Config          :: Shiro file: file://C:\Documents and Settings\ezsusmu\Downloads\apache-jena-fuseki-3.17.0\run\shiro.ini
16:13:32 INFO  Config          :: Template file: templates/config-tdb-mem
16:13:32 INFO  Server          :: Database: TDB1 dataset (in-memory)
16:13:32 INFO  Server          :: Path = /Susan
16:13:33 INFO  Server          :: System
16:13:33 INFO  Server          ::   Memory: 7,1 GiB
16:13:33 INFO  Server          ::   Java:   1.8.0_201
16:13:33 INFO  Server          ::   OS:     Windows 10 10.0 amd64
16:13:33 INFO  Server          ::   PID:    14568
16:13:33 INFO  Server          :: Started 2021/03/08 16:13:33 CET on port 3030

ezsusmu@SE-00018098 /cygdrive/c/Documents and Settings/ezsusmu/Downloads/apache-jena-fuseki-3.17.0
$ java -jar fuseki-server.jar --memTDB /Susan
16:14:50:050 INFO  Server          :: Apache Jena Fuseki 3.17.0
16:14:51:051 INFO  Config          :: FUSEKI_HOME=C:\Documents and Settings\ezsusmu\Downloads\apache-jena-fuseki-3.17.0\.
16:14:51:051 INFO  Config          :: FUSEKI_BASE=C:\Documents and Settings\ezsusmu\Downloads\apache-jena-fuseki-3.17.0\run
16:14:51:051 INFO  Config          :: Shiro file: file://C:\Documents and Settings\ezsusmu\Downloads\apache-jena-fuseki-3.17.0\run\shiro.ini
16:14:51:051 INFO  Config          :: Template file: templates/config-tdb-mem
16:14:52:052 INFO  Server          :: Database: TDB1 dataset (in-memory)
16:14:52:052 INFO  Server          :: Path = /Susan
16:14:52:052 INFO  Server          :: System
16:14:52:052 INFO  Server          ::   Memory: 7,1 GiB
16:14:52:052 INFO  Server          ::   Java:   1.8.0_201
16:14:52:052 INFO  Server          ::   OS:     Windows 10 10.0 amd64
16:14:52:052 INFO  Server          ::   PID:    16720
16:14:52:052 INFO  Server          :: Started 2021/03/08 16:14:52 CET on port 3030
```

As you can see, changed from logging seconds to milliseconds as well.

The default is Console, not to a log file.  You can change that by looking into log4j more :)

[image]

Comment: I have put it into the base folder (i.e. where fuseki-server.jar is) and also the run folder. Nothing happens. There might be something really obvious I am missing, but these instructions do not make that clear to me.

Comment: and you are using this https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/main/jena-fuseki2/apache-jena-fuseki/log4j2.properties??

Comment: Yeah. What should I see? I have checked the logs folder, I do not see anything there. When the INFO comes up at start up, I see my config loading, I see my shiro.ini loading. But nothing about log42j

Comment: I updated my answer.  Hope that clarifies things

Comment: Thanks Susan for going into a bit more detail. I tried making the change you recommended. I had also added the following to the properties file to get it to write the log to a file: 

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LogToFile
appender.file.fileName=logs/app.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

Sadly, none of these things appear to make any difference.

Comment: It looks like I found the problem, or at least my problem. I downloaded the latest version of Fuseki which is 3.17.0. I was using an older version 3.13.1.